# [@[COLUMN_NAME]] reference in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, tableau-api

I've inherited a MS Excel workbook from a stalled project. I now need to reverse engineer and experiment to see how it all works. How does the formula know which value to fetch? I was expecting to see a cell reference.

```
=CONCATENATE([@[HAL '#]],"-",[@[Data Dimension]],"-",A3)
```

- "HAL #" is a column header in worksheet (not the worksheet the formula is in)
- "Data Dimension" is a column in the same sheet as the formula
- "A3" is a column in the same sheet as the formula its a 3 digit number

**Context**
This will eventually feed a Tableau work flow...that's all I know...for now

**What I've tried**

- I've changed values in the HAL and Data Dimension column. Sometimes
  the value in the last parameter fetches the row of that column,
  sometimes not...
- There are no macro in this workbook
- THere are no named range that resemble HAL (and Data Dimension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAL # must be a column in the same table. Excel won't let you save a formula with an invalid column reference. Check for hidden columns.